# I can't use rn-nodeify with React-Native - weird package.json problem

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, mobile, node-modules

I'm developing a mobile app using React-Native, which involves an interaction with a private Ethereum network; for that reason, I need to include Web3.js in the project.
Problem is, as you may know, that RN does not support core Node.js modules ( and I need crypto for using Web3.js).
I'm pretty a newbie in RN, so I searched the Web and found out that rn-nodeify should solve my problems;
so, I made
npm i --save rn-nodeify

added it in the dev-dependencies, then I tried

./node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --install --hack

but it gives me this error:

```
    C:\Users\adr\Desktop\TestNatvi\mobileapp\node_modules\.bin>rn-nodeify --install --hack
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
      throw err;
      ^
    
    Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\adr\Desktop\TestNatvi\mobileapp\node_modules\.bin\package.json'
    Require stack:
    - C:\Users\adr\Desktop\TestNatvi\mobileapp\node_modules\rn-nodeify\cmd.js
    [90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)[39m
    [90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)[39m
    [90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)[39m
    [90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)[39m
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\adr\Desktop\TestNatvi\mobileapp\node_modules\[4mrn-nodeify[24m\cmd.js:18:11)
    [90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)[39m
    [90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)[39m
    [90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)[39m
    [90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)[39m
    [90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)[39m {
      code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,
      requireStack: [
        [32m'C:\\Users\\adr\\Desktop\\TestNatvi\\mobileapp\\node_modules\\rn-nodeify\\cmd.js'[39m
      ]
    }
```

This is the  package.json file in the main project directory:

```
    {
      "name": "TestNatvi",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "android": "react-native run-android",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios",
        "start": "react-native start",
        "test": "jest",
        "lint": "eslint ."
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
        "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.9.2",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.6",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.3",
        "asn1.js": "^5.4.1",
        "asn1js": "^2.0.26",
        "buffer": "^5.7.0",
        "crypto": "^1.0.1",
        "react": "16.13.1",
        "react-native": "0.63.3",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
        "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
        "react-native-paper": "^4.2.0",
        "react-native-randombytes": "^3.6.0",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.1",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.8",
        "react-native-screens": "^2.11.0",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
        "util": "^0.12.3",
        "web3": "^1.2.11"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
        "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
        "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
        "eslint": "^6.5.1",
        "jest": "^25.1.0",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1",
        "rn-nodeify": "github:tradle/rn-nodeify"
      },
      "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
      }
    }
```